# How do I use ngFor with an Observable in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ngfor

I am having trouble emitting data from my observable using *ngFor.

I have the following call in my data service:

```
    completedTasks(): Observable<Array<Todo>> {
       return this.aHttpService.get<Array<Todo>>(
              'http://localhost:3000/todos?complete=true');
    }
```

Then, I have this property to get the data:

```
  get completedTodos(): Observable<Array<Todo>> {
     return this.todoDataService.completedTasks();
  }
```

Then, I use the following HTML to get the data out:

```
 <li *ngFor="let todo of completedTodos | async" >
   ... stuff here
 </li>
```

However, while I can see via Postman that there is JSON in the API call, nothing appears in my list.

I'd gladly have the call to `completedTasks` return an Array if I could figure out how to convert an observable to an array (if that even makes sense....)

**Update:**

I changed the code, which did indeed have `completedTasks` instead of `completedTodos` (thank you), and now I get:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `let todo of completedTasks` be `let todo of completedTodos` ?

Comment: @Brandon  It should, thank you.  Corrected.

Comment: I would recommend storing the result of `this.todoDataService.completedTasks();` in a variable rather than using a `get`, otherwise it will be called on every change detection cycle

Comment: Looks like the service call is returning a single JSON object and not an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is basically correct. Here's a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbrgjc) that outputs an Observable array of objects.

The only thing I did differently was assign `completedTodos` as a view model property during `ngOnInit()`. This prevents the observable from being created on each change detection cycle.

Alternatively, if you wanted to use a getter, you can use a ChangeDetectionStrategy of OnPush.

[Update]

I changed the example code to retrieve a list of todos from: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ so it makes an actual GET request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [subscribe](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing) to an observable in order to get any data from it.

Comment: The `async` pipe *does* subscribe to an observable: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: I was under the (perhaps mistaken) impression that `async` does the subscribing....

Comment: @Nick Hodges they do subscribe.